# how to make group join and leave functionality in Django?

Tags: django

```
def join_group(request,pk):
    group = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    group.members.add(request.user)
    return redirect('home')
```

urls.py

```
path('create_group', views.create_group, name="create-group"),
path('group/<str:pk>', views.group, name="group"),
path('join_group/<str:pk>', views.join_group, name="join_group"),
```

feed.html

```
 <a href="{% url 'join_group' group.id %}">  
      <p class="roomListRoom__topic">
        Join
      </p> 
 </a>
```

I have a group in my app. I wanted to make the join and leave functionality. Join functionality is working properly but I want to make whenever anyone clicks on (join) then he should be redirected to that particular group when I change the return redirect to
' return redirect ('group/' + str(pk)) ' then i am getting URL like 127.0.0.1:8000/join_group/group/8.....

and I want to make that if the user is joined to the group then there should be joined instead of join and join for other users. - using if statement

and I want to make leave functionality:

please help me to get out of these problems.. if you need more info .. I am ready

thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions here, so I've split them out below:

1. **URL redirect not working** - Your redirect does not start with a forward-slash, so the path you are providing to redirect will be appended to the current path - hence why you now have `join_group/group/8` - your options are to add the slash or to use URL names, like so:

   `redirect('group', pk=pk)`

   This is a better way of managing URLs than hardcoding them.
2. **Show 'Joined' in group view** - you want to show within the template that the person is a member of that group, you can achieve this by doing the following:

   ```
   {% if request.user in room.users.all %}
      # show joined or leave 
   {% else %}
      # show join button
   {% endif %}
   ```

   It might look slightly differently depending on what field links user and room.
3. **Create a 'Leave' view** - you can do the same as your join view but in reverse:

   ```
   group.members.remove(request.user)
   ```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove